# How to only check top level (pom-listed) packages for updates with "Versions Maven Plugin"?

Tags: maven, maven-versions-plugin

Currently the check for updatable modules takes a huge amount of time.
It seems as if the module does not only check the direct project dependencies but also the indirect dependencies - which does not really make sense (in most of the scenarios).

I did not find an option to just check the packages listed in the pom - but not the indirect dependencies of these packages.

Is there such an option?

Comment: Can you explain how often you run that check ? Usually you should do that once a day or maybe once a week on a CI solution? Can you also please show which command you are exactly using?

Comment: It was - for now - just a try at all. So I will not run this with every build ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not talking about transitive (indirect) dependencies, but about the entries of `<dependencyManagement>`.

You can deactivate the search there by setting `processDependencyManagement` to `false.`

Comment: No. I am talking exactly of the "indirect"/"transitive" dependencies: "[...] packages listed in the pom - but not the indirect dependencies [of these packages] [...]". - Added "of these packages" to make it more clear.

Comment: I don't think the Versions Maven Plugin looks for those dependencies at all. Please add a console output to show this. I think that Maven only looks for dependencies and dependencyManagement.

Comment: There is also an configuration https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report-mojo.html#processDependencyManagementTransitive  where you could turn off processing of transitives...